# Is it safe to position a dual-antenna WiFi USB adapter on the top of a computer case?

Tags: wifi, desktop, antennas

I have a Tp-Link Archer TX20U Plus dual-antenna USB adapter, connected via USB cable to my desktop workstation, and I'd like to know if it's **safe** to position it on the top of the case of my workstation.

Could there be interference or other kinds of malfunctions?

Comment: To the user who downvoted this question: Would you care to explain the reason why? What's wrong with this question? How can it be improved?

Comment: Almost every electronic you can buy in North America goes through [EMC Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_compatibility) to ensure it works correctly in the presence of radio waves. There is nothing unsafe for the computer coming from that antenna.

Comment: Just noticed this question in the list (sorry, the topic is out of my area, so can't help). But just a guess on the downvote--the question is probably considered a bad fit for this site. Hardware Recommendations focuses on identifying hardware that meets specific requirements. Your question is about a product's operational use. I'm thinking Super User would be a much better site for this. You might want to ask a moderator here to migrate it for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yes**

if you consider a microwave oven which operates at 2.4ghz the same frequency as old 802.11g, has it's door grill screen mesh about the same size as a computer case vent mesh, and if the computer case is largely metal... even if one side is transparent plastic... the antenna on top of the case won't have a radiation pattern going downward into the case.

Not to mention motherboards that come with wifi, 802.11ac and ax which happens also in 5Ghz; their little wifi antenna that connects via SMA to the back of the motherboard where the USB ports are (which i would consider a *less safe* antenna placement in terms of possible interference) and they all work with zero problems caused.